# Haskell: How to convert string into boolean Matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix, type-conversion

I need some help with Haskell. 
I want to read a string and convert the string into a list of lists of boolean values. 
For example `"LLL\nbbb\nLLL"` should produce the following list: `[[True,True,True],[False,False,False],[True,True, True]]`. Anything else should be ignored.

I am new to the idea of functional programming. I tried the following:

```
StringParse :: String -> Matrix
StringParse s =
    case s of
            "L" -> Matrix [[True]] 
            "b" -> Matrix [[False]]
```

With datatype Matrix:

`data Matrix = Matrix [[Bool]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first split up your task in subproblems.

- Partitioning the list in blocks for each newline. Handily, there's a standard function which does exactly that: `lines`.
- Removing anything you don't expect. That could be a job for `filter`.
- Translating each `L` into a `True` value, each `b` into a `False`. That's just a `map` operation.
- The previous two steps need to be done for each block / line, so you again need to use `map` to apply them both to the list of lines.
- Pack everything in a `Matrix` data constructor.

Chaining all together is incredibly easy in Haskell:

```
parse :: String -> Matrix
parse = Matrix . map (map decide . filter isKnown) . lines
 where decide 'L' = True
       decide 'b' = False
       isKnown 'L' = True
       isKnown 'b' = True
       isKnown _ = False
```

That would be a perfectly good solution.

Actually though, it's probably better here to merge the 2nd and 3rd steps: rather than first picking out the values we can deal with at all and then handling the same set of values with seperate cases, we can do both at the same time. The IMO nicest way, though it's perhaps confusing for you right now, is to use the fact that lists are monads:

```
parse' :: String -> Matrix
parse' = Matrix . map translate . lines
 where translate line = do
         ch <- line
         case ch of 'L' -> [True]
                    'b' -> [False]
                    _   -> []
```

Comment: This is just great. That is why I am learning Haskell, but I guess I need way more practice. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do notation? What is this, imperative programming? ;)

Comment: @Tetigi Well you *could* use a comprehension instead: `[ bool | ch <- line, bool <- case ch of 'L' -> [True]; 'b' -> [False]; _ -> [] ]`

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it down into small steps.

You want to convert a string like `"LLL\nbbb\nLLL"` into `Matrix [[True, True, True], [False, False, False], [True, True, True]]`.  So that means you want to turn that string into `[[True, True, True], [False, False, False], [True, True, True]]`, then wrap it in `Matrix`.

this means that you want to process each line individually, so you'll want to turn `"LLL\nbbb\nLLL"` into `["LLL", "bbb", "LLL"]`.  Handily, Haskell has a built in function called `lines` that will do this for us, it splits a string on newlines.  So let's write down what we can so far

```
parse :: String -> Matrix
parse s = Matrix $ {- something -} lines s
```

So how do we turn a line into a list of booleans?  We turn each individual character into a boolean, then apply that operation to each character.  So first, we should write a helper function to match the characters we want

```
charToBool :: Char -> Bool
charToBool 'L' = True
charToBool 'b' = False
charToBool _   = False -- Catch-all.  With this you don't actually need the 'b' case
```

Notice that this converts a *Char* into a Bool.  Now we can map it to a whole line

```
lineToBools :: String -> [Bool]
lineToBools line = map charToBool line
```

Now, we just need to apply this operation to all of the lines we have

```
parse s = Matrix $ map lineToBools $ lines s
```

And you're done!

---

There is a shorter, better way of doing this.  First, unless you truly have a need for it, don't bother wrapping `[[Bool]]` in a constructor, just use a type alias

```
type Matrix = [[Bool]]
```

Next, these functions can be inlined somewhat

```
parse s = map (map charToBool) $ lines s
```

And this can be ETA reduced to

```
parse = map (map charToBool) . lines
```

But, `charToBool` can be inlined as well into `(== 'L')`, so you can write the entire thing as

```
parse = map (map (== 'L')) . lines
```

Which I like a lot more.

---

If you want to filter out unexpected input, you could also do

```
parse = map (map (== 'L')) . map (filter (`elem` "Lb")) . lines
```

and keep it in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

```
parse :: String -> Matrix
parse = Matrix . map (map (=='L') . filter (\x -> x=='L' || x=='b')) . lines
```

Should do the trick :D

Edit: Should work now, thanks Tetigi and bheklilr!

Comment: No it won't, you need to wrap it up in the Matrix constructor first!

Comment: Additionally, if you want to full on ignore anything that's not L or b, you should insert a filter (\x -> (x == 'L') || (x == 'b')) in there

Comment: Also == "L" will return a type error as that's a [Char] rather than just a Char 8D. I think you want 'L'

Comment: It should also be `'L'`, not `"L"`